# which algorithm is applicable to predict multiple output values using "machine learning"

Tags: testing

I'm trying to predict values four target numeric variables, using machine learning, I am very new to machine learning concepts, 
Please help me out to create a model for the below mentioned dataset.
Please suggest which approach to use in order to predict multiple values.
I seriously don't know how to start and where to start and which algorithm to use.

Here is my input data set and output data set.

**Input Dataset**

```
    // Input dataset
        {
      "width":1000,
      "height":500
      "objects": [
        {"left": 27.76, "top": 27.5, "width":671, "height": 197},
        {"left": 312.2, "top": 154.27, "width":499, "height": 452},
        {"left": 707, "top":41.3, "width":1000, "height":714}
      ]
    },
    {
      "width":1000,
      "height":500
      "objects": [
        {"left": 30.12, "top": 37.5, "width":721, "height": 217},
        {"left": 360.2, "top": 160.27, "width":530, "height": 520},
        {"left": 720, "top":60, "width":1200, "height":814}
      ]
    },
    {
      "width":1000,
      "height":500
      "objects": [
        {"left": 35.12, "top": 40.2, "width":721, "height": 217},
        {"left": 370.2, "top": 170.27, "width":540, "height": 530},
        {"left": 800, "top":90, "width":1250, "height":910}
      ]
    }
```

**Output Dataset**

```
{
  "width":1000,
  "height":500
  "objects": [
    {"left": 40.27, "top": 30, "width":671, "height": 197},
    {"left": 370, "top": 160, "width":499, "height": 452},
    {"left": 750, "top":50.13, "width":1000, "height":714}
  ]
},
{
  "width":1000,
  "height":500
  "objects": [
    {"left": 35.15, "top": 47.3, "width":721, "height": 217},
    {"left": 410, "top": 190, "width":530, "height": 520},
    {"left": 650, "top":90, "width":1200, "height":814}
  ]
},
{
  "width":1000,
  "height":500
  "objects": [
    {"left": 45.12, "top": 45, "width":721, "height": 217},
    {"left": 390, "top": 185, "width":540, "height": 530},
    {"left": 820, "top":100, "width":1250, "height":910}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please try to visualize as rectangle between input and output. 
only "left" and "top" values are varying. May be it is aligning to different position. 
how it is aligning will define the algorithm. 
Also please mention dataset size

Comment: For now, i am trying just by varying the left and top properties , to make less complicated

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too generic. So, I will take the liberty to answer it theoretically.

Let's say you are talking about prediction of a variable in the dataset. So, the first thing you need to do is to have a prepared dataset with all variables (conversion of categorical variables should be done) and derived variables can be added to dataset. Once the dataset is prepared, you need to create a training dataset and test dataset. On the training dataset you can create your model. Once the model is created you can evaluate the model using the test dataset to predict the variable you are interested in (eg Car Price in case of car dataset).

Now, some theoretical things: Basically, predictive analytics have 3 types of ML algorithms i.e Regression, Classification and Clustering. Depending on the need you need to select one of these. Regression is to predict a continous variable. Classification is to categorize the dataset by lables. Clustering is to identify unknown clusters.

In regression problem, there will be multiple Independent variables that will be used to predict the value of a dependent variable (Eg. Car price is predicted based mileage, car weight, height, length, horsepower etc). Here car price is a dependent variable and all other variables are Independent in nature.

Identify what you wish to do and then apply the concepts.